# Highchart, how add text on pie pieces?

Tags: javascript, text, highcharts, label, pie-chart

have a PIE chart, I need show text on pie pieces like [**here**](http://image.dieselpowermag.com/f/news/1004dp_april_2010_postal_route/28636993/1004dp_05+diesel_power+april_2010_postal_route+pie_chart.jpg) and code on example what I have [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wbpBY/1/).

Part code here:

```
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        ...
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 12.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                },
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
    });
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use "distance" attribute by default it is 30. negative value results in data labels on the pie chart.

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    distance: -55
 }
```

updated your jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wbpBY/2/)